# Pass function of function as parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a method `setBuildQuery` and I want that it can receive as parameter a function `x`. The function `x` should take as input an indefinite number of parameters and output another function `y`. 
Function `y` takes as input two dates and outputs a string.

Examples using a function notation

```
x = (one_f)(from_date, to_date) => string                      or
x = (one_f, two_f)(from_date, to_date) => string               or
x = (one_f, two_f, ..., n_f)(from_date, to_date) => string
```

How can I model this in Scala (i.e. how can I say to a function to accept a function x of this type?
How the user of my app can specify this function as a `val` ?

I was thinking something like function of function or high order functions. I am not too familiar with them in Scala though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters.* The best you could do is take a function that takes a Seq:

```
def setBuildQuery(f: Seq[YourType] => (Date, Date) => String)
```

You could then define a function it accepts like this:

```
val f: Seq[YourType] => (Date, Date) => String =
    ls => (from, to) => ???
```

* You can have a method that takes an arbitrary number of parameters, but that doesn't help here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do that, you can use Partial Application to define your function.

The function will not execute until you invoke it with all its parameters

```
def x(head:String, tail:String*)(from:Date, to:Date): String = {
  println(head) // it doesnt exec until from and to are provided
  "result"
}

val y = x("string1", "string2") _

y(new Date, new Date)
```

or you can return a function

```
def x(head:String, tail:String*): (Date,Date) => String = {
  println(head) // it exec before from and to are provided
  (from:Date, to:Date) => {
    "result"
  }
}

val y = x("string1", "string2")

y(new Date, new Date)
```

Comment: That's not partial application, that's currying/multiple argument lists.

Comment: x is partially applied here `val y = x("string1", "string2") _`

Comment: Yes, but you're not using "Partial Application to define your function."